# ReactiveCrudRespository never returns from SaveAll

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

At startup, I check for some data and if not present attempt to save some defaults (temporarily for testing).

```
val subs = repo.findAll().toIterable()

if(subs.none()) {
    repo.saveAll(defaults.map { Source(it.link.hashCode().toLong(), it::class.java.canonicalName, arrayOf(it.link)) }).blockLast()
}
```

On the first run, we will reach the saveAll() but never unblock. The data is saved in MongoDB, and I can confirm it with Robo 3t.

Subsequent runs with data actually present will lead to the first findAll never unblocking.

Profiling in MongoDB appears to show a successful query.

[Profile of findAll() query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrerX.png)

My Respository and Entity are as follows:

```
interface SourceRepository : ReactiveCrudRepository<Source, Long> {
    //
}

data class Source(
        @Id val id: Long,
        val type: String,
        val params: Array<String>
)
```

This is in Kotlin, against Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4. I am targeting a MongoDB instance running in docker. If I remove this bit of startup logic, my other ReactiveCrudRepository is able to read/write just fine, never blocking.

The working Repository's saveAll() call also concludes in a blockLast(), as I found that without this the save would never actually occur.

Comment: This appears to be happening because I am trying to create the Bean in my main configuration, and perhaps the Repository hasn't finished initializing at this point?

If I move the code to a component which is only accessed later and do not try to use it as a bean the issue seems to go away.

Comment: I'm having this issue but with it not being in the configuration steps. I have a simple rest controller that finds all records it needs to update via a couple filters and then tries to save everything. :/