# Sprint Boot 2.0 Applications (Reactive MongoDB) hangs up on startup

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm new to Spring Data with Reactive MongoDB and am having troubles with my [generator](https://github.com/phip123/reactive-hangs/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/reactivehangs/Generator.java). Both setup methods won't return. The first one is

```
@PostConstruct
public void setup() {
    personRepository.deleteAll().block();
    LOG.info("Never happens");
}
```

The deleteAll() call will block indefinitely.  I'm experiencing the same problem when executing this

```
@PostConstruct
public void setup2() {
  List<Person> personList = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        personList.add(Person.PersonBuilder.aPerson().uuid(UUID.randomUUID()).name("Name " + i).build());
    }

    personRepository.saveAll(personList).blockLast();
}
```

It seems like the repository won't close the connection when using block() or blockLast(). In the case of saveAll() many connections are opened but not closed.

Edit: I know this is not really reactive, but I don't want have to chain everything in this class. In case there is no way this could work, I'm happy to see your suggestions. As I said I'm fairly new to this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking further I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748962/reactivecrudrespository-never-returns-from-saveall).

Then I got the idea to provide a CommandLineRunner Bean and insert the data there. Now everything works as expected. I also updated [the repository](https://github.com/phip123/reactive-hangs/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/reactivehangs/ReactiveHangsApplication.java).